# UITextField and UIWebView Input Text Field response times

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uikeyboard

My iOS app needs to use a `UIWebView` Text Field for input.

**The problem is** - there seems to be a slight delay in time for the Keyboard to show up after clicking the UIWebView's input text field.

Is there some way to adjust the delay to be next to nothing?

`UITextField` shows the keyboard up instantly, the second it's tapped it's animating to show, so I'm wondering if I can get that sort of instantaneous response time with a `UIWebView's` text input field.

Answer (score 0):

Click events in UIWebViews have a delay in iOS. Use ZeptoJS, bind a "tap" event on the input and then focus the input.

```
$("#field").tap(function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
```

I made a demo, test it on your iPhone or iPad http://jsfiddle.net/Sy35B/4/embedded/result/